# Kibana 7.1x (7.16 for me) resets colors when editing "vertical bar" visualization type

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-7

When I edit a vertical bar vizualisation in kibana, the histogram colors reset to the default value each time I edit the visualization.

Before I click on the edit button (from the dashboard view)

[image]

After the click "edit visualization", I obtain the following graph with the default colors.

[image]

Is there a way to avoid this behavior?